# JavaScript mouseout triggered when over children

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseout

I am working on menu to my website and I need to user over/out to show/hide submenu + animation.

I got the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/JyTPW/

When I `mouseover` "products" and then go to child element, the `mouseout` is triggered. I tried to fix it but I failed.
I read all the posts about checking the reltarget and etc but still I failed to make it work.

I would really appreciate your help.

**Edit**:
After long search I found [Cross-browser event registration](http://icodesnip.com/snippet/javascript/cross-browser-event-registration) which provide mouseenter and mouseleave.
It fixed my problem.

Comment: @erimeturk, I just converted my whole jQuery to regular javascript. it saves me 90kb + faster proccess. I dont want to use jQuery.

SamuelLiew, I dont want to use CSS3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you think about it, it is doing it as expected. But not as a programmer would like it. Microsoft went the way of doing what you wanted. Everyone else, didnt.
The solution? Use jQuery and listen to the custom [mousenter/mouseleave event](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

Comment: i don't think jquery is the solution, `one solution` could be use to jquery, but again its not the the solution.

Comment: yes, its one solution. You could also do the whole handling and parent checking yourself, while traversing the DOM and handling all the inconsistencies between browsers. But there isn't a different event, that handles his issue like he wants.

Comment: I dont want to use jQuery. I just converted my whole jQuery to regular javascript. I need javascript based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the jQuery source (open source is the best) you can see how they implemented it.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/91824bd2923b99b03fd1a9c4447b46fd7cc96615/src/event.js#L659

While some jQuery APIs are used inside the handler you can clearly see how it works.  It checks the `mouseover` event object and checks if the `relatedTarget` is the element itself or a descendant.  If it is, it calls the callback triggers mouseleave.